# IIS redirect into subdirectory

Tags: iis, redirect

I have under my default web site the directories:

```
/myapp/
/myapp/v1/
/myapp/v2/
/myapp/v3/
/myapp/administration/
```

Now I would like to http-redirect all users who type `/myapp` or `/myapp/` or `/myapp/index.html` in their browser, to `/myapp/v3/index.html`.

Requests coming to

```
/myapp/favicon.ico
/myapp/typeyourfilenamehere.html
```

should not be forwarded. But the only option I found was "Only redirect requests to content in this directory", but that would include not only the `index.html`, but also `typeyourfilenamehere.html`.

How can I configure the aforementioned behaviour in IIS?

EDIT: Thanks to the quick answer of @JamesRyan, "IIS URL rewrite 2.0" has just put the following into my Web.config:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="/myapp">
                <add key="/myapp" value="/myapp/v3/" />
                <add key="/myapp/" value="/myapp/v3/" />
                <add key="/myapp/index.html" value="/myapp/v3/" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Umschreibregel1 für /myapp" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{/myapp:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

At a quick glance, it works as indented, but perhaps someone could explain me what each line tells the rewrite engine.

Answer (score 1):

Use an URL rewriting module, then you can redirect according to any pattern you like with whatever exceptions you like.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

You can install this IIS extension which will let you rewrite request strings based on regular expressions.

The interface differs depending on which version of IIS you're using. What version are you on?

Comment: Personally I prefer one that uses the standard apache regex rules